# displaying images from mysql in php in rows and cols

Tags: php, mysql

i need to display images from mysql in my gallery. i have a responsive template. i have around 40 images in my mysql i want to fetch images and display it in gallery view of 4 column per row and it should go to the next set

here is my code for the html gallery

```
<ul class="row box2">
       <li class="span4">
       <img></img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img></img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img></img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img></img>
       </li>
</ul>
```

so above is my code i need to repeat this code for every 4 image i show from Mysql using php so that i can form a gallery

pls help in looping this for every four image fetched so that i disaplay all my 40 images in 10 rows 4 per column

thanks in advance

Comment: how you store img in db, just link or ... ?

Comment: jus links i store image in folder

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to devide you main Array with all images into small array with 4 images

as example:

```
$mainArray;// here the value of all images from db
$resultArray = array_chunk($mainArray, 4); //now you have arrays which include 4 images
```

And then use foreach to build block as you want

```
<?php    foreach ($resultArray as $minArray){ ?>
   <ul class="row box2">
     <?php foreach ($minArray as $array){ ?>
       <li class="span4">
       <img><?php echo $array['img']?></img>
       </li>           

     <?php  } ?>
  </ul>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$i=0;
while = ($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource)){
    if($i==0){
        ?><ul class="row box2"><?php
    }
    ?>
    <li class="span4"><img src='<?php echo $row['image']?>'></img></li>
    <?php
    $i++;
    if($i==4){
        ?></ul><?php
        $i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your questing correctly but you can use for loops .  Is this what you want?

```
var x;
var y = 1;
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
x = x + '<ul class="row box' + i + '">
       <li class="span4">
       <img> '+ imageArray[y] +' </img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img> '+ (imageArray[y] +1) +'</img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img>'+ (imageArray[y] + 2) +' </img>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
       <img>'+ (imageArray[y] + 3) +'</img>
       </li>
</ul>';

y++;
```

}